# Scapy: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getlayer'

Tags: python, python-3.x, scapy

So, I wrote a portscanner which worked wonderfully. It outputted everything I wanted. But at some point, I've broken it and I can't identify how I broke it.

The error I'm getting is:

```
line 12, in portscan
    if(tcp_connect.getlayer(TCP).flags == SYNACK):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getlayer'
[Finished in 4.4s with exit code 1]
```

Here is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import logging
logging.getLogger("scapy.runtime").setLevel(logging.ERROR)
from scapy.all import *

def portscan(host,dst_port):
    src_port = RandShort()
    SYNACK = 0x12
    RSTACK = 0x14
    tcp_connect = sr1(IP(dst=host)/TCP(sport=src_port,dport=dst_port,flags="S"),verbose=0,timeout=2)

    if(tcp_connect.getlayer(TCP).flags == SYNACK):
        send_rst = sr(IP(dst=host)/TCP(sport=src_port,dport=dst_port,flags="AR"),verbose=0,timeout=2)
        print (dst_port,"is open")

    elif (tcp_connect.getlayer(TCP).flags == RSTACK):
        print (dst_port,"is closed")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    host = '192.168.0.40'
    port = 80
    portscan(host,port)
```

I'm not sure what I've changed in order for me to break it. Any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: Apparently `tcp_connect` is `None`. Have you done any debugging?

Comment: I'm trying right now, but I can't see what I've done wrong lol

Comment: The first step would be to find under what circumstance `sr1` returns `None`. IS that one of your functions?

Comment: ["If there is, no response a None value will be assigned instead when the timeout is reached."](http://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html). `None` being returned means there was no response. You'll need to check for that. Side Note: Scapy has to have some of the worst docs I've seen. I can't even find a function-by-function breakdown.

Comment: Would that be best done with a try catch? 
`if(str(type(tcp_connect_scan_resp))=="<type 'NoneType'>"):
        print ('dead')`
This is a method I've seen online but it doesn't seem to work for me yet

Comment: No. Just do `if tcp_connect == None: (Handle Failure); else: (Handle success)`. Comparing it against the type string is super hacky. I'd be sceptical of anyone suggesting doing that.

Comment: Yep, that works. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Carcigenicate pointed out:

> If there is no response a None value will be assigned instead when the timeout is reached. None being returned means there was no response. You'll need to check for that . . .

The solution:

```
if tcp_connect == None: 
     (Handle Failure)
else: 
     (Handle success)
```